# Get Y-value related to X-Value in plotly.js

Tags: plotly

I use plotly.js to draw time series. I'm trying to get Y-value for given hover X-position (in hover event). I can get the value if I'm at the data point (or near enough) but I would need to get the value even in zoomed-in view when the data points are far away each other and the hover X-position is in between them.

Is there a function in plotly.js to achieve this? 
(The value should be interpolated for linear data, ideally corresponding to the line drawn. For stepped data it should be obviously the last state value at that position.)

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am looking for the exact same thing right now.

Comment: @FloWin Not really, I opened a thread at Plotly's forum http://community.plot.ly/t/function-to-get-y-value-related-to-any-x-value-in-hover-event/1956 and created a sample to get interpolated values for other traces but the hover is bound to data points. You can see the sample here: http://codepen.io/exavier/pen/wWLbQv/ to get inspired

Comment: That is just what i was looking for! Thanks a lot.